# Why is there an exclamation mark at the end of the folder in VS Code?How can I remove it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I just added the folder to my Workspace

Comment: a different color means some file in the directory or subdirectory has a problem

Comment: Try some of the fixes suggested here (probably a duplicate question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992459/vs-code-can-not-resolve-workspace-folder